# on form closing event i am puzzeled

Tags: vb.net, messagebox, formclosing

I want it so when the "x" button is clicked a message box will appear saying "Are you sure you  want to exit?" then if "yes" it closes and if "NO" it stays open. so my code is:

```
Dim a As Integer
a = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", _
                    "Vice Versa 1.0", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information)
If a = vbYes Then
  Me.Close()
Else
  Exit Sub
End If
```

This should work, no? When i debug my project clicking "no" still exits my program. Is this just because it's in debug mode or am i missing something here?

(EDIT:) Also no warnings or errors.

Is there a way i can make my game pause when the message box shows? I only have it working to if the users presses "p" on keyboard. But also want game paused when message box shows, without pressing "p"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to set the Cancel property to cancel the close. On the line before `Exit Sub`, add:

```
e.Cancel = True
```

and you don't have to do the Me.Close again. A better way to write your If block would simply be to have:

```
a = MessageBox.Show(....)
If a = DialogResult.No Then
    e.Cancel = True
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still very new to this. But i should have thought of that haha. I know that programming everything has to be called for or set and all that. I thought that end sub was good enough. On the bright side though, i'll never forget that. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: yes i realized that after i seen my "yes" button was not doing anything except what seemed to be restarting the popup. so i changed the me.close already. But thanks again.